# Boxplots at different vertical levels of decreasing pressure failing to produce a single level

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe formatted with the following columns:

`Date Station model Height (m),  model Pressure level (hPa),  Unnamed: 4,  Observed temp (°C),  HRRR temp (°C),  Temp Difference,  Unnamed: 8,  Observed dwpt (°C),  HRRR dwpt (°C),  Dwpt Difference`

I'm to create a chart with boxplots for the Temp Difference column, where each boxplot represents the spread over a given pressure level. Each box plot will only contain rows where model Pressure level (hPa) matches the given pressure level

my pressure levels are as follows:

`pressure_levels = [1000, 900, 800, 700, 600, 500, 400, 300, 200, 100]`

And the block of code that produces the plot looks like this:

```py
# get data only at discrete levels

pressure_levels = [1000, 900, 800, 700, 600, 500, 400, 300, 200, 100]
data            = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []] # compartemantalize data by level

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(len(metrics_pressure_coords[0])):
        if metrics_pressure_coords[0]['model Pressure level (hPa)'].iloc[j] == pressure_levels[i]:
            data[i].append(metrics_pressure_coords[0]['Temp Difference'].iloc[j])




# figure and axes for boxplots

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 10))

# Boxplot
bp = ax.boxplot(data, vert = 0, showfliers=False, patch_artist=True)


# axis formatting
ax.grid(alpha=0.3)
ax.set_axisbelow(True)

ax.set_yticklabels(pressure_levels)

# ax.set_xlim(-3.5,3.5)
ax.set_title('Boxplots for All Temperature Discrepancies at different levels')
ax.set_xlabel('Temperature Discrepancy (\N{DEGREE CELSIUS})')
ax.set_ylabel('Pressure at top of level (hPa)')


# format boxplots
for patch in bp['boxes']:
    patch.set_facecolor('pink')
    
for median in bp['medians']:
    median.set(color ='black', linewidth = 1)
```

The chart that is produced, looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, all levels are plotting except for pressure level 200. Despite my best efforts, I cannot get it to plot.

Looking into the data, I see that `data[8]`, which represents the Temperature Difference data at pressure level 200 does have data, If I run the following:

```py
print(len(data[8])) # check how much data we have

for temp in data[8]: # check if any datapoint is not a number
    if type(temp) != np.float64:
        print('fail')

print(data[8][0:5]) # print a few data points
```

This will output the following:

```
4280
[1.4794555664062727, 0.6138977050781449, 3.046984863281274, -0.1452758789062258, -0.1287475585937301]
```

When I tried making a boxplot of just the 200 pressure level, I get no output, but when I just run an `ax.plot` I am able to get output, so I'm at a loss as to why the data isn't plotting

Comment: Did you check for `np.NaN`? Or Seaborn's `sns.boxplot` which ignores NaNs?

Comment: @JohanC Doesn't look like there are any NaNs, but switching to seaborn did fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Well, it is not really a "fix", it is rather a different interpretation of what should happen with NaNs. Seaborn tries to simplify things and create the visualization you might have wanted.  Matplotlib's boxplot considers NaN values as unknown, so it doesn't want to create a boxplot before you manually either filter out the NaNs, or replace them with some default.

Answer (score 0):

As JohanC said, it may be an issue with the types of values in `data[8]`. I switched to Seaborn and it works fine now. Here's the converted code and plot:

```py
pressure_levels = [1000, 900, 800, 700, 600, 500, 400, 300, 200, 100]
data = {level: metrics_pressure_coords[0][metrics_pressure_coords[0]['model Pressure level (hPa)'] == level]['Temp Difference'] for level in pressure_levels}

# Convert data to a list of lists for Seaborn
data_list = [data[level].tolist() for level in pressure_levels]

# Create the boxplot using Seaborn
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 10))
bp = sns.boxplot(data=data_list, orient='h', showfliers=False, color='pink', ax=ax)

# Find the median lines and set their properties
medians = [median_line for median_line in ax.lines if len(median_line.get_ydata()) == 2]
for median in medians:
    median.set(color='black', linewidth=1)

# Axis formatting
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.grid(alpha=0.3)
ax.set_axisbelow(True)
ax.set_yticklabels(pressure_levels)
ax.set_title('Boxplots for All Temperature Discrepancies at different levels')
ax.set_xlabel('Temperature Discrepancy (\N{DEGREE CELSIUS})')
ax.set_ylabel('Pressure at top of level (hPa)')

plt.show()
```

[image]